# Make a RadMenu with a persisting sub-menu bar?

Tags: drop-down-menu, menu, navigation, telerik, submenu

I'm exploring Telerik documentation about persisting web pages and page navigation, and I like the look of [RadTabs with persistence](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/tabstrip/examples/application-scenarios/persisting-tabstrip-settings/defaultcs.aspx?skin=Silk&show-source=true).  I want to have a submenu that spans the width of the screen appear like it does here.

RadTab, however, doesn't look sufficient as my goal is something like the [sample RadMenu](https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/menu/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx) where I would use the ?Page= query string and actually link to pages.

This *is* a MasterPage navigation bar I'm aiming to make, and only a few links will open into a submenu the rest will immediately load a new page.
Is there something I'm missing in RadMenu that would achieve the look of the RadTab submenu, while maintaining the usage of RadMenu and it's query strings?

Answer (score 0):

Looking into it more, it looks like you can treat RadTabs as links.

Instead of providing MultiPages to them, you can supply a NavigateUrl parameter to the tabs.

```
<telerik:RadTab Text="Tab Text" NavigateUrl="/" />
```

Will look like a tab, and act like a link.  Though I'm running into other issues preventing me from using the tabs as breadcrumbs, it appears as though the ?page= query string approach will work with tabs as well.